# ASP.Net Core Authorization of local users + LDAP

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, ldap

It is necessary to give the system the ability to authorize users using local accounts (like a regular identity from the box), and using Active Directory accounts (via an LDAP provider any). How can this be done in the ASP.Net Core project, and how can I register such an authorization method in the system (meaning Startup class)? In previous versions, as far as I know, it could be solved using FormAuthentication, but before logging on, check the user in one of the providers (you can force the user to specify in advance the type of his account). I do not know how to do this in ASP.Net Core and I have not found similar examples on the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*System.DirectoryServices* is not available in ASP.NET Core yet as of today. You can read more [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2089). However, we can use [Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard).

```
public bool ValidateUser(string domainName, string username, string password)
{
   string userDn = $"{username}@{domainName}";
   try
   {
      using (var connection = new LdapConnection {SecureSocketLayer = false})
      {
         connection.Connect(domainName, LdapConnection.DEFAULT_PORT);
         connection.Bind(userDn, password);
         if (connection.Bound)
            return true;
      }
   }
   catch (LdapException ex)
   {
      // Log exception
   }
   return false;
}
```

For authentication and authorization, we can use *Cookie Authentication Middleware*  with claims.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
   ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {                
      AuthenticationScheme = "AuthenticationScheme",
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
      AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Common/AccessDenied"),
      AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
      AutomaticChallenge = true
   });
}
```

It has few moving pieces, so I created a [working sample project](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit) at GitHub.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful answer! It contained enough material that I could understand how it works.